# How to replace TSQL cursor and scalar functions

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, cursor, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application that runs a simulation on temporal data.  The calculations are are not overly complicated however the calculation requires previously predicted temporal data in the same simulation.

Let's assume a simulation using 1 week of data with data points at 15 minute interval. The simplified calculation for a predicted value is as follows:

```
PredictedValue = A + B + C + D
```

To get the values of B, C, and D, the simulation requires previously calculated data at t0, t-1, t-95, t-96, t-672 and t-673.  This is the temporal data for the current and previous interval, previous day's current and previous interval and the previous week's current and previous interval.

I have a working implementation that simulate data over any time period however performance is extremely poor with large datasets.

The implementation uses a TSQL cursor to loop over the temporal data under simulation and scalar function to retrieve the previously calculated data.

Basically the larger the dataset the slower the simulation runs.  For example, a simulation using 1 day of data takes < 1 minute; a simulation with a month of data takes 2-3 days.

I'm really interested in how I can improve the performance of the TSQL code without using a cursor or the scalar functions.

Comment: share some code for your existing implementation. We can help you re-write it using sets instead of cursors

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: Performance issues with date/times are often related to indexes (or a lack thereof) and using functions inappropriately in the WHERE clause(s).  If you force the DB engine to apply functions to every row in the table, e.g. WHERE YEAR( DATE_COL ) > 2000, you'll see performance decrease as the table grows.

Comment: I will post some code later today.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would suggest using a self-join. SQL server is then able to process your query as a set giving a tremendous speed increase.

Simplified example, assuming the table has two columns (date, value) and is called Data

```
SELECT (A.value + B.value) as Prediction
FROM [Data] A left join [Data] B
ON B.date = dateadd(day,-1, A.date)
```

(done without testing so may contain typo's - but I hope you get the picture).

Good luck, Otto.